# Is there a way to locate something relative to a grave?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

In Persian, objects can be located in respect to a grave. For instance, and these are words that I've made up myself just to give you an idea of what I'm looking for:

Upper head region: Any place above the position of the head of the corpse.

Under feet region: The region after the feet of the corpse.

These are probably very vague definition, so please check the image that has been attached.

[image]

**Edit**: A sample sentence, in response to @mike65535:

Normally, the mourning ceremony begins with the crowd gathering in the "upper head" of the grave and performing religious rites, and then moving towards the "lower feet" for the family of the deceased to bid farewell.

Edit 2: In Persian, the words are بالا سر (read Bala Sar) and پایین پا (read Payeen pa)

[image]

Edit: Spelling

Comment: Can you give an example sentence?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Are you asking about parts of a *grave* (the site of a burial), or parts of a *casket* / *coffin* (the box containing the corpse)? What are the Persian words? I cannot think of any widespread customs in the Anglo-American world that require the general public to have terms for different parts of either, but undertakers may have specialized terminology.

Comment: Head and foot are used as in headstone and footstone. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I'm sure this belongs on another website, but I've no idea which one.

Comment: "I'm sure this belongs on another website, but I've no idea which one." - a creepy one.

Comment: A "corpse" is a dead body. A corps (silent "p" and "s") is a military army. A "body" can be dead or alive. A grave is a place where dead bodies are buried. A body is put in a coffin and that is often buried in the ground.

Comment: "Upper head" isn't a common English expression, but it would mean the top part of the head itself, and so "upper head region" would be the area immediately around *and including* the upper head, not a position above the head.

Comment: I doubt we would use any more detailed terms than 'head' and 'foot' of the grave.

Comment: @choster Neither the grave nor the casket; I mean the area surrounding the grave.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you for pointing out to the typo.

Comment: @nnnnnn What about the lower feet region?

Comment: Head and foot is perfectly fine. See the dictionary definitions in my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In light of the edit and clarification, I would suggest that family and friends pay their respects at the **head** of the grave, and then bid their farewells at the **foot**. You could also say the **top** and **bottom** [end] of the grave.

> **[head](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/head)**
>   **3.** The front, forward, or upper part or end of something
>     **3.1.** The upper end of a table or bed.

> **[foot](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/foot)**
>   **3.** The lower or lowest part of something; the base or bottom.
>     **3.2** T**he end of a** bed, couch, or **grave** where the occupant's feet normally rest.

Definitions taken from Lexico (formerly Oxford Dictionaries)

NB
Just saw Owain's answer, which is almost identical, so making this a Community Wiki post

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it time to tag this topic as 'solved'?

Comment: @hossein there is no solved tag because answers can be posted later on which can shed further light. But as the author of the question you can choose which answer to "accept", which is like saying your problem has been resolved. Click on the grayed check-mark beneath the bottom arrow, it should turn green as you do so.

Comment: I would also agree with 'head' and 'foot'. We don't have words for the areas outside the grave because (in the UK) you only buy enough 'plot' to drop the coffin into, and we don't move around the grave during the ceremony.

Answer (score 1):

I quote the following private email sent to me by a local authority cemetery officer in the UK:

> It is possible to have 3 x cremation urns in the same plot.  First one
>   is interred at **the head of the grave**, 2nd **in the middle** and the 3rd **at
>   the foot end**.

There doesn't appear to be a distinction between *at the head end* and what you call *upper head region*, because in the UK a grave would not normally be opened to put *eg* a cremation urn on the same level as and next to an existing coffin.

Comment: You see, this is all about the grave itself. What I'm trying to find is the land beyond the head or below the feet. It's not in the grave itself.